# Create and Add Controls and Attach Events to them at Runtime in Excel UserForms

Tags: excel, vba, events, userform

recently I found a very useful article about [“How to add Events to dynamically created Controls in Excel using VBA class module”](https://www.encodedna.com/excel/how-to-add-events-to-dynamically-created-controls-in-excel-using-vba.htm). I tried it in my project and it worked perfectly for just one textbox at a time. Actually I have to create multiple textboxes dynamically using VBA "For Next Loop" and attach the same event to all of them explicitly. but only the last created textbox gets the event.
Would you please help?

userform:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

' Create and add the textboxes.
Dim i As Integer
For i = 0 To 4
    Set tbPin = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1")
    With tbPin
        .Top = 8 + (i * 20)
        .Left = 10
        .Width = 130
        .Name = "thePin"
    End With
    
    Set objMyEventClass.tbEvents = tbPin        ' Attach an event to the textbox.
Next
' Create and add the button control.
Dim btEx As MSForms.CommandButton
Set btEx = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.CommandButton.1")
With btEx
    .Top = Me.Height - 60
    .Left = 10
    .Width = 130
    .Height = 25
    .Caption = "Submit"
End With

Set objMyEventClass.btEvents = btEx         ' Attach at event to the button.
End Sub
```

class module:

```
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents tbEvents As MSForms.TextBox
Public WithEvents btEvents As MSForms.CommandButton

Private Sub tbEvents_Change()
    If Len(UserForm1.tbPin) > 6 Then
        MsgBox "Max 6 digits only"

        With UserForm1.tbPin
            .Text = ""
            .SetFocus
        End With
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btEvents_click()
    If Trim(UserForm1.tbPin) <> "" Then
        Call showMyPin(UserForm1.tbPin)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub showMyPin(pin As String)
    MsgBox "You have entered " & pin
End Sub
```

Comment: You can use a global Collection object to store each of your event-handling class instances (one for each pair of controls)  Similar Q:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35789529/add-multiple-dynamic-controls-to-userform-and-assign-different-event-handlers-to

Comment: Have you see [VBA – Control Arrays](http://www.siddharthrout.com/index.php/2018/01/15/vba-control-arrays/)